# For loop containing if statements does not loop again

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, netbeans

Below is a method that takes in `student`array and the `topStudentIndex`of a value calculated by another method previous.

I have multiple objects in my array. However, the for loop only managed to loop through once, and it returned the first value straight away.

I have no clue why the for loop stopped even though my `st.length`is more than

```
public static int computeNextHighestOverallStudentIndex(Student[] st, int topStudentIndex) {

    double nextHighestOverall= 0;
    int nextHighestStudentIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
            if ((st[i] != null) && (!(i == topStudentIndex))){
                double studentOverall = st[nextHighestStudentIndex ].getOverall();
                if (studentOverall > nextHighestOverall) {
                    nextHighestOverall= studentOverall;
                    nextHighestStudentIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }
    return nextHighestStudentIndex ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like

```
double studentOverall = st[nextHighestStudentIndex ].getOverall();
```

should be

```
double studentOverall = st[i].getOverall();
```

since you want to check all the Students in the array and not just the first one (`st[nextHighestStudentIndex ]` will always return the first Student, since you initialize `nextHighestStudentIndex` to 0).

Comment: thank you @Eran, after changing it worked. I will accept your answer in a moment, for the timer to expire

Answer (score 1):

You want to traverse the entire array using st[i] (not st[nextHighestStudentIndex])